# .first() works, but not :first-child or :odd

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I got a bunch of .tileItem elements in my DOM tree. I want to give the 1,3,5,7,... element a margin-right.

The problem is, when I select the elements like this it does not work:

```
$(".tileItem:odd").css("margin-right","2%");
```

This works neither:

```
$(".tileItem").find(":odd").css("margin-right","2%");
```

I was curious and tried the following:

```
$(".tileItem:first-child").css("margin-right","2%");
```

No luck at all.

Here comes the interesting part: **When I try this:**

```
$(".tileItem").first().css("margin-right","2%");
```

It works like a charm. Of course only the first element gets set, but why does this work and all the other selectors fail?

Comment: Try `$(".tileItem:nth-child(1)")`

Comment: This led me in a good way. Actually $(".tileItem:nth-child(2n+1)") did it!

Comment: **Note** :odd actually select element number 2,4,6, etc. You would need to use :even. This is due to zero-based indexing. I.e. it selects the odd indexes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.first()` returns the first element in the set and not necassarily the first child

See docs:
http://api.jquery.com/first/

Depending on what your html looks like, but if you want the children how would this work:

```
$('.tileItem').children(':even').css("margin-right","2%")
```

**Note** that because of zero-based indexing, `:odd` actually selects the second element, fourth element, etc. That is, the odd index number 1,3,5... That's why I've used `:even` to select the first, third, etc. element as per your question.

jQuery docs on [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)

This can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Although I was able to solve it by myself, now I understand why I got this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
$(".tileItem:nth-child(2n+1)")
```

worked out.

Comment: `$(".tileItem:nth-child(2n+1)")` will work the same as `$(".tileItem:even")` but in your question, you are asking for `:odd`

Comment: See my answer for explanation on odd/even selector

Comment: I thought that :odd would address the 1,3,5,7,... but actually, as PostureOfLearning said, :odd addresses 2,4,6,... and :even addresses 1,3,5,7,...
I didn't know that I needed the :even selector. I thought the :odd selector is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors weren't quite correct for what you wanted to accomplish, here's a brief explanation why:

```
$(".tileItem:odd").css("margin-right","2%");
```

This `:odd` will filter the set of matched elements, so rather than giving the child elements a right margin, you tried to assign it to the `.tileItem`s themselves. If your tileItems are not block-elements (e.g. through setting `display: block` or `display: inline-block`), this will have no effect.

```
$(".tileItem").find(":odd").css("margin-right","2%");
```

`find()` will search for direct descendants that match the selector, for each item in the first set. This means that it would try to apply the right margin to every second descendant in each `.tileItem`.

```
$(".tileItem:first-child").css("margin-right","2%");
```

This *should* have worked, but again only if that first child is a block element (See http://jsfiddle.net/YfX7L/)